# How to set per fragment home up indicator icons

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, fragment

I've been searching all day with no success...

I have one fragment (A) in an activity that adds another fragment (B) to the backstack.  I should note that fragment A and B are in the same container, such that when B is added, A is no longer visible until B is complete.  I can set the home up indicator icon for both fragments successfully.  When fragment B's home up indicator is selected, I remove the fragment from the backstack & fragment A is shown again.  However, fragment A now has the home up indicator icon from fragment B.

How can fragment A know when fragment B is done so that it can set the home up indicator again and do other necessary tasks?

I've tried checking in onCreate, onActivityCreated, onCreateView, onViewCreated, onResume, etc. but none of those seem to be called after fragment B is removed.

Environment:
Android Studio 0.8.9
Project is set for API 16 to 21
Using AppCompat for the action bar, fragments, etc. (thus, NO ActionBarSherlock answers please!)

Comment: "However, fragment A now has the home up indicator icon from fragment B." Just pop the backstack when you show fragment A again using the fragment transaction. That should remove fragment B from backstack and do the trick for you.

Comment: @Nazgul, thanks for the response, but that hasn't worked.  I still end up with fragment A having fragment B's home up indicator.  Moreover, fragment A seems unaware that anything occurred, so it cannot respond appropriately.